# Finding the angle measure from standard position

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

The question asks what the angle is from standard position being represented in the picture. The answer is $-670$ degrees however I think the answer is $-680$ degrees..

What am I getting wrong?

One rotation counterclockwise has an angle measure of $-320$ (since the angle given is $40$). Then a second rotation would be $(-320+(-360))=-680$

And the diagram looks like it stops after two rotations.

Part b of the question asks "What is a positive angle measure above $360$ degrees that is coterminal with this angle measure?"

Since the angle is $-680$, the first coterminal angle that is greater than $400$ degrees is $-680+360+360+360=400$

But the answer is $410$ degrees. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that $-670^\circ + 3 \cdot 360^\circ = -670^\circ + 1080^\circ = 410^\circ$.  Your error lies in your first calculation, as Allawonder's answer explains.

Answer (score 1):

From the $+x$ axis, you make one complete turn clockwise. That's $-360°.$ Then you turn an angle less than a full turn -- precisely $-(270+40)°.$ Thus you've turned a total of $-670°.$